# issue of default file permission of user rhel 6

Tags: files, permissions, rhel, umask

We have one network user and two Rhel servers.

When we are creating file on server 1 using this network user, default permission of `-rw-r-----` is getting assigned to file but if same user is creating file on server 2 then default permission of `-rw-r--r--` is getting assigned to file.
`umask` for this user is set to 027 on both the servers.

I am not sure what is missing on server 1 as we are expecting the permission of `-rw-r--r--` for both the servers for new files.

Comment: The `027` mask causes files at `0640` (`-rw-r-----`) and directories at `0750` (`drwxr-x---`). You must have other differences, an ACL perhaps? One can only guess without knowing the permissions of each directory from the root of the file system to the file creation directory. (`ls -lZ`) each directory.

Comment: To make Christopher's remark a bit more concrete: What is the output of `getfacl .` in the directories where the file is created?

Comment: What is your definition of a "network user"? How does this account create the file on server1 and server2 (Direct login? NFS? FTP? CIFS? Something else?) Please provide this extra information in your question so it's easy for everyone to see.

Comment: In case you didn’t understand what Christopher said: `-rw-r-----` is the correct result for a umask of 027.  Why are you expecting `-rw-r--r--`?